# add script tag in module joomla

Tags: joomla

I am new in joomla.I am working on form submit in joomla..so i have create one form by creating module in joomla(please mention if there is another way to create form and send email). Now I user jquery form steps to create form wizard..by following code in default.php in joomla
default.php(mod_inquire folder)

```
$doc->addScript( JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_inquiry/js/jquery.steps.min.js' );
```

I also added css

```
$doc->addStyleSheet( JUri::root() . 'modules/mod_inquiry/css/jquery.steps.css' );
```

Now my question is where to put script tag in defaul.php,some how I added

```
<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                alert();
                jQuery("#wizard").steps({
                    headerTag: "h2",
                    bodyTag: "section",
                    transitionEffect: "slideLeft"
                });
            });
        </script>
```

but it says .. jQuery(...).steps is not a function...Any help would be appriciable...

Comment: I think nobody have knowledge in joomla..........:)

Comment: Have you added jquery latest version min file ? Please add this in your code *before script tags* `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong syntax for including a file.Update the path constant, use `JURI::root()` Instead of `JUri:root()`. For more detail check this link : https://docs.joomla.org/JURI/root

You can use `addScriptDeclaration` to add JavaScript code:

Ex.

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();

// Add Javascript
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            alert();
            jQuery("#wizard").steps({
                headerTag: "h2",
                bodyTag: "section",
                transitionEffect: "slideLeft"
            });
        });
');
```

Comment: but it is working with JUri and also i see that jquery steps css and js also added

Comment: As per the error there must be possible that Jquery is not getting loaded before your script. Either try to put your code at the bottom of the page after jquery library gets loaded. Or you can add the Jquery in the same mobule file before your script. But it's not good practice to use multiple jquery library. It may be possible jquery get's conflict.

Comment: you can turn on error reporting all php error from configuration and for javascript you have to check in the console.

Comment: please share a link so that i could know how to get error in php

Comment: GOTO->Global Configuration->Server Tab-> Error Reporting , Set this to maximum and save.

Comment: jQuery steps is not function

Comment: That's clearly indicates that either "jquery.steps.min.js" not included or you are calling jQuery.step function before the "jquery.step.min.js". Please check the source code in view source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80571/discussion-between-vrajesh-and-toretto).